# What is the relation between $x$ and $y$ in the range of this function?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, multivariable-calculus, diophantine-equations

We have that:
$$289>143x-210y>-289$$
Where $x,y\geq17$

So, for any given $x$, what is its relationship with $y$?

That is to say, for any given $x$, how do I identify the $y$ values that hold true to the constraints mentioned above?

Also, in which cases would both $x$ and $y$ be integer values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$289>143x-210y>-289$$
$$289-143x>-210y>-289-143x$$
$$\frac{143x-289}{210}<y<\frac{143x+289}{210}$$